# How to prevent dropdown menu in Boostrap from closing onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How do you prevent the dropdown menu class in Bootstrap from closing whenever a link inside is clicked?

I want users to select one of the class "type-of-visitors" and also be able to select one of the options in the select field without closing the dropdown menu.

& the "Go" button will be the one closing the menu.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="#" class="type-of-visitors">Total visitors</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="type-of-visitors">Paid visitors</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="type-of-visitors">Social media</a></li>
   <li>Compare data 
    <select>
     <option>Last month</option>
     <option>Last week</option>
     <option>Last 3 months</option>
    </select>
   </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Go</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the jsfiddle to it: http://jsfiddle.net/stan255/cU6Y5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a similiar question posted about this and the answer should suffice

*"The issue is that the boostrap dropdown jQuery plugin closes the dropped-menu when you click anywhere else. You can disable that behavior by capturing the click events on your dropdown-menu element and keeping it from reaching the click event listeners on the body element."*

Just add

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
 });​
```

Comment: How can I use this in Typescript. I'm working on Angular 6. Please help me.